# Initialising parentView of parentView issue

Tags: ios, swift, parentviewcontroller

I have a `viewControlle`r with `containerView and`**`UIPageViewController`**.

I'm calling editingProfile method but it won't pass into **parentNewCarRequestVC**. But once I make an action  it passes into **parentNewCarRequestVC**. So please how I can initialise the parentView once the screen start.

I'm so sorry if I didn't explain my issue well.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    editingProfile()
}

func editingProfile(){
    if let parentVC = self.parentViewController as? UIPageViewController{
        if let parentNewCarRequestVC = parentVC.parentViewController as? NewCarRequestViewController{

            print("DONE")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try calling your method in `override func viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: I called the method in the viewDidLoad but it didn't work :( @AbhishekSharma

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions must be wrong. Do this:

```
func editingProfile(){

   print(self.parentViewController)
   print(self.parentViewController.parentViewController)

    if let parentVC = self.parentViewController as? UIPageViewController{
        if let parentNewCarRequestVC = parentVC.parentViewController as? NewCarRequestViewController{

        print("DONE")
    }
}
```

}

Show us the debugger output for both prints.

Comment: The output:
1st: Optional(<UIPageViewController: 0x15d56b1f0>)
2nd: nil

Comment: Could you tell me please why it enter once I make any action?

Comment: So your parent of parent is nil. It's pretty simple. If it is "nil" your code will never reach DONE.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. So is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

call ur method id viewDidLoad. If u want to call in viewWillAppear then initialise in viewDidLoad and

## parentNewCarRequestVC = parentVC.parentViewController as? NewCarRequestViewController in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I'm sorry how could I initialise in viewDidLoad?